# VLCJ - RTP stream can't unpause mp3, however can unpause mp4

Tags: vlcj

I Create the mediaListPLayer like this(basically copied from VLCJ examples)

```
public Player() {
    this.ip = "127.0.0.1";

    factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    mlp = factory.mediaPlayers().newMediaListPlayer();

    /*
    mlp.events().addMediaListPlayerEventListener(new MediaListPlayerEventAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void nextItem(MediaListPlayer mediaListPlayer, MediaRef item) {
            System.out.println("Playing next item: " + item + ")");
        }
    });
            */

    playList = factory.media().newMediaList();

}
```

I assign the playlist to the player like this (list of strings comes from socket)

```
public void setPlaylist(String[] strings, int port) {
    String options = formatRtpStream(this.ip, port);

    playList.media().clear();

    for (String s : strings) {
        playList.media().add("F:\\Biblioteca\\" + s, options);
    }

    mlp.controls().setMode(PlaybackMode.LOOP);
    MediaListRef playlistRef = playList.newMediaListRef();
    try {
        mlp.list().setMediaList(playlistRef);
    } finally {
        playlistRef.release();
    }
}
```

I pause and unpause using this method, on the server side. r is just for sync purposes

```
private String pauseUnpause() {
        mlp.controls().pause();
        return "r";
    }
```

on the client side, I start and catch the stream like this (out is a socket)

```
private void playFromList() {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> r = (ArrayList<String>) MediaList.getSelectedValuesList();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("p##");

        for (String str : r) {
            sb.append(str);
            sb.append(";");
        }
        out.println(sb.toString());
        out.flush();
        empc.mediaPlayer().media().play("rtp://127.0.0.1:" + port);
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e){
        System.out.println("Lista Vazia");
    }
}
```

The stream itself works flawlessly. At least until I pause it
When I press a button, it sends a request trough a socket that calls the pause/unpause function. Here's the thing. when I'm playing video (mp4), the pause/unpausing works. However, when I play an mp3 file, it pauses, but then it doesn't unpause. It just plays for a tenth of a second or nothing at all and stops. But if I tell it to skip, the skip does work and it starts playing the next song, meaning the player isnt dead or something. I don't understand why it would work for video but not music.
Any help is very aprreciated

Comment: Have you double checked for a vbr and non vbr mp3?

Comment: @Kamil.S no... Does that matter?